# How soon would I get banned from Github for scripting contributions?

Tags: github

If I wrote a script that made a Github contribution/commit about once per second, at what point would Github catch on and suspend my account? I clearly states that doing this is not allowed but how would they know? This is entirely theoretical and I'm just curious how these sites enforce these rules.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pertains to an internal implementation detail of GitHub, and not a specific software development question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main reasons that this kind of behavior gets detected.  First, one reason is that it looks inauthentic and follows a pattern of spam and abuse, in which case the folks dealing with that will detect it with automated tools and usually suspend the account without further notice.  For example, if you are opening junk pull requests, that will get shut down pretty quickly, since it causes a nuisance to others.

If you simply push a large number of commits to a repo that are autogenerated, especially if you're pushing frequently, someone will notice because you are making lots of pushes and some graphs show an abnormality, because your repository will contain a huge number of commits and time out when repacking, or otherwise because you cause some sort of minor problem (dashboard anomaly, alert, etc.).  This kind of problem actually happens reasonably frequently.  As long as it's a minor problem and isn't impacting availability, you'll be asked to stop by staff via an email.  If you continue the behavior or don't respond, either the repository or the account will be suspended.  If it's impacting availability, the account will be suspended while staff reach out, and possible IP blocks may occur if that's necessary.

In general, GitHub serves a lot of repositories, and if you are doing your thing and not causing a problem for GitHub or other users, then you will probably be left alone.  If your resource usage comes to GitHub's attention, then you're using a whole lot of resources, and that's going to be a problem.  Same thing goes for behavior and conduct.

As a side note, this is one reason that it's helpful to always authenticate or otherwise identify your client (e.g., for the API, using a distinct user agent with a URL, username, email, or other contact info in it).  If you're using excessive resources, GitHub would much rather reach out and ask you to stop, since that's usually much easier and more effective in solving the problem, rather than just suspend or block the account or IP.  However, it is always preferable when people use a reasonable amount of resources and that doesn't become necessary.